# Make only mobile based website

Tags: html, responsive-design

I am less confused to make a website only for mobile and tablet not a desktop. I need to know only one thing.

1. Should I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and define `@media only screen` for specific device?

Comment: Can anybody help me out?

Comment: have a look at this link,hope it helps : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thanks NiMa for your help. I now understood what should I do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however your website still will be accesible from other devices.I can explain it for you:

Using  tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It will adjust webpage width to match device width and set initial scale to 1 (no zooming). So for example, if you open this page using iPad, web browse will display page in 1024x768 (landscape) or 768x1024 (portrait).

```
initial-scale=1
```

This will force to display webpage with zoom set to 1.

Using media queries CSS3 you can set different CSS styles for different devices:

**Styles for Tablets**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

   /* Styles for tablets */
 }
```

**Styles for Desktop**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

   /* Styles for Desktops */
 }
```

Comment: What exactly I am looking for. Thanks for your clear description and clear my confusion. :)